# Restrict input of PK if generated by sequencing and triggers in oracle 11g xe

Tags: database, triggers, oracle11g, primary-key

I know we can restrict the insert operation on PK in application logic if sequencing is used. Is there any way to restrict insert if you are inserting outside of application e.g. From SQL developer or SQL plus. And if there is, kindly, elaborate it since I am newbie.

Pardon me if it is obvious

Regards

Comment: It's not very clear what you want to achieve. Do you want to prevent users from directly setting the PK when they perform an `INSERT` in some SQL tool (e.g. SQL/Plus) ? (BTW, when talking about RDBMS systems, the word `querying` is usually used only for `SELECT` statements)

Comment: @frank Schmitt Sorry for being vague. I will edit the question and yes you are right I would like to restrict insert operation on PK when it is being generated sequentially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trigger is probably just ignoring any user-supplied primary value anyway, if it's simply setting the PK column from the sequence without checking:

```
begin
  :new.pk_column := seq.nextval;
end;
```

You sometimes see the supplied value taking precedence with something like this:

```
begin
  if :new.pk_column is null then
    :new.pk_column := seq.nextval;
  end if;
end;
```

... which gives you flexibility, but without control; so someone can manually enter a high key value, and when the sequence gets to the same value you get a key clash an ORA-01001 unique index violation, which is not ideal. From your comment it sounds like you might have this situation at the moment.

If you want to make it more obvious and actually prevent users *trying* to set the primary key, rather than silently ignoring (or accepting) whatever value they supply, you could check whether the key column is being set as part of your trigger, and throw an exception if it is:

```
create or replace trigger ...
...
begin
  if :new.pk_column is not null then
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'Do not set a value for primary key');
  end if;
  :new.pk_column := seq.nextval;
  ...
end;
/
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4526f/1).

You would need to disable or modify the trigger during a bulk load of data that includes keys, such as importing from an earlier export.

You could also hide the primary key column entirely by creating a view of the table that has all the other columns, and then have an instead-of trigger that still generates the primary key from the sequence. But the primary key probably needs to be visible, at least if they ever want to use it to find related records using that as a foreign key.

Comment: I used the trigger that comes with SQL developer as default and I think, may be I am at mistake, It wasn't ignoring user typed value when I performed insert operation. May be I did wrong with something else

Comment: @chaudry - not sure which default you mean. It would be clearer if you added the original trigger statement to the question. But it *might* have been choosing to accept the passed value - sometimes people want it to work that way, but it tends to leas to problems with clashing keys at some point, so I think it's good that you aren't leaving it like that.

Comment: so can I use the trigger you provided?

Comment: @chaudry - you should modify your existing trigger(s) to do the same kind of check; it might be setting or validating other things, so replacing it blindly might cause problems.  This will prevent a value being supplied manually though, and stop the insert happening if someone tries.